# View with Block and Page results in Pager Issues

Tags: 7, views

I have a view that has a Block and a Page. The block is up in the header of the site as seen in the first image below and obviously the page is loaded in the content area.

The odd behaviour is that when I turn on the pager on on the Page under the view it displays in the block in the header and not in the page. If I turn the pager on for both it duplicates the pager in the dropdown that is the block in the header so they are both there and not one in the block and one in the page. The pager variable isn't even available in the page view.

Is there something that would be causing the pager to be put in the block only? There is nothing in the code that I can tell that is causing this behavior.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: The "More link" option is available on Page views, but why it's behaving the way it does for you is difficult to say. Are you overriding any templates for Views? When you inspect HTML of the Block and Page below content what does it show?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Two pagers, but the second one doesn't show](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/298820/two-pagers-but-the-second-one-doesnt-show)

Comment: @prkos no it doesn't. The original developer has a block view and a page view but neither seem to be overriding default behaviour of the pager out put. There are other pages in the system that are setup that doesn't present this issue. However as I said though the block and the page are being displayed on the same page. So I do not know if that could be causing he issue or not.

Comment: Argh someone deleted the original q while I was mid-replying. You posted a lot more info in the original q, this one should have been closed/deleted while the original one should have been kept. Anyway, you were testing the wrong code, you're not using "Pager" from the Pager section of the Views, you're using "More link" from the Pager section. You should be testing `$more`, above the `$pager` code.

Comment: I just went a reversed the delete. IT wasn't me but it let me undelete it. Let me give it a try but even still with pager active it still doesn't show. Ok let me go test this right quick.

Comment: Ok so it doesn't output at the end of the page at all even with $more. It is putting it in the dropdown from the block in the header and not in the page content.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117312/discussion-between-the-gugaru-and-prkos).